# Removing Selected Session items (VB ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I am working on something which requires various session Data to be held.

I need to be able to delete certain data from the session, but not clear the whole thing.

Obviously, I can manually delete session items with

```
Session.Remove("itemName")
```

My question is, is it possible to do something like set a prefix to all session variables and then delete all variables with that prefix?

```
useData = session("snippet_theData")
```

and then something that does

```
Session.Remove("snippet_*")
```

...rather than having to manually remove each item individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all... I'm afraid the above didn't quite work, I'm using VB and from the errors I was getting, it looked to me like the methods above would work in C#, but failed with VB.

Anyway, you pointed me in the right direction and I now have this:

```
    Dim Key As String
    Dim prefix As String = "prefix_"
    Dim deleteKeyArray As Array
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim deleteKeys As String

    For Each Key In Session.Keys
        If Key.StartsWith(prefix) Then _
            deleteKeys = Key & "," & deleteKeys
    Next

    deleteKeyArray = Split(deleteKeys, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(deleteKeyArray)
        Session.Remove(deleteKeyArray(i))
    Next
```

Seems to do the job.

Answer (score 7):

The most direct way would be to iterate through the session collection and use either a simple string match (`string.StartsWith`) or a regular expression (overkill if your IDs are really as simple as `snippet_`), and either use `Session.Remove()` to remove the item, or set its value to null or an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
 Const prefix = "snippet_"
 Dim prefixKeys = (From sessionKey In Session.Keys
                   Let name = CStr(sessionKey)
                  Where name.StartsWith(prefix)).ToList
 If prefixKeys.Any Then
     For Each key In prefixKeys
         Session.Remove(key.name)
     Next
 End If
```

Note: the `ToList()` is needed because you cannot remove it from Session during iteration otherwise(deferred execution).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use linq to get all the keys that you want (you'll have to excuse my vb.net as I mostly code in c#):

```
Dim myKeys = Session.Keys.Cast(Of String).Where(Function(k) k.StartsWith("snippet")).ToArray()
```